# Get all attributes type in assembly (reflection)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, .net-assembly, custom-attributes

I'm trying to get all the attributes of a certain type present in the assembly. In my specific case I have attributes on Controller and others attributes on Actions (MVC). With this code I can get what I want, but I'm quite sure there is a way to avoid the union

```
var assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
var myAttributes = assemblyTypes
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>()).ToList();
myAttributes = myAttributes.Union(assemblyTypes
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods())
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>())).ToList();
myAttributes = myAttributes.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: What is the problem with using *Union*? As an alternative *Concat* can be used?

Comment: I wonder if maybe it can be done without the Union, something via Reflections. When I use GetMethods I can obtain attributes on all Actions, but not attributes existing on Controllers and inherited Controllers. For example something like .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethodsPlusControllers())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any reflection method that gives parent type and its members together, so the best solution is simulating that behavior using `Append` like this:

```
var assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
var myAttributes = assemblyTypes
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods().Cast<MemberInfo>().Append(x))
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>())
    .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying, however the question asks if it is possible to avoid union (in favor of reflection, and if it is possible to do so, also the code). This means that if the union cannot be avoided, a negative response will also be accepted.